# Viewing a file in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal

I'm working through The Command Line Crash Course by Zed Shaw and I'm on the View a File Section.  I ran into some trouble because I think I've done everything right but "less" doesn't seem to be an alias in Powershell.

I've tried `Get-Content` but so far nothing.  The other command I've tried is `get-content ex12.txt -wait`.  I looked through the Get-Alias and I haven't been able to locate anything which looks like what I need to use.

---

EDIT

So it looks like I copied the file incorrectly, which was the problem.  Still working on how to do that.  Not quite at question stage yet, I'm hoping I can work through it.

---

EDIT2

It looks like you copy by:

`C:\Computer\User\Folder1 ex12.txt ~/Folder2`

(I just learned this and I'm writing this from memory.  YMMV)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `more`or the `Out-Host` Cmdlet with the `-paging`switch:

```
Get-Content ex12.txt | Out-Host -Paging
Get-Content ex12.txt | more # more is a less equivalent
```

If you want to use less, you could also create an alias for it:

```
Set-Alias -Name less -Value more
Get-Content ex12.txt | less # Now less can be used
```

Comment: Okay, I think I am still unclear as to what Get-Content is supposed to do, I'm coding something incorrectly or I'm not including something in my code.  I type in: `cd temp` then `Get-Content ex12.txt | Out-Host -Paging` then `Get-Content ex12.txt | more` and I didn't get an error but also nothing happened.  I typed in `ls` and ex12.txt is listed in temp.

Comment: @AAlex Does the file actually contain anything? The pager doesn't do anything unless the text exceeds the terminal size.

Comment: The file contains 2 lines of text.  Should I not have included the -Paging?  I'm trying to get the lines of text to print into the terminal is my understanding the of the commands.  Thanks.

Comment: @AAlex Paging has the purpose to display text one screen/page at a time when the text is longer than a single screen/page. With that said, it's still not clear to me what your actual problem is. Please describe the actual behavior and how it differs from the desired behavior [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31908028/edit).

Comment: I'm getting the impression from the comments that I'm supposed to be seeing the text from my text file on my desktop when I type in the code which I typed in in my first comment.  My document has text in it, when I left out -Paging it threw an error `cannot find patch` but when I don't include paging it just goes to the next line and expects me to put in more commands.  I only have two lines of text in my text file.

Comment: Sorry, in my terminal, not on my desktop.

Comment: @AAlex Please provide evidence that demonstrates the problem. Please **put it in your question**. Please **do not** post it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Less it's a Unix command,

"Less is a program similar to more, but which allows backward movement in the file as well as forward movement. Also, less does not have to read the entire input file before starting, so with large input files it starts up faster than text editors like vi "

In powershell you can use more

```
Get-content ex12.txt | More
```